# ios NSArray get all index between 2 index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array that contains the following

```
"Dave.",
    "Dave is an awesome guy",
   Dave Lan,
"Josh.",
    "Josh is funny",
   Josh Nepy,
"Zach",
    "Zach is too lazy",
   Zach Sung
```

and I want to get the first name from each one, any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Can you describe the array structure a bit more clearly.

Comment: Please post your code; your question as it stands doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It looks like an array of NSDictionarys should be a better structure. How is the array being created?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{
                        @"name" : @"Dave",
                        @"desc" : @"Dave is an awesome guy",
                        @"fullName" : @"Dave Lan"
                        };

NSDictionary *dict2 = @{
                        @"name" : @"Josh",
                        @"desc" : @"Josh is funny",
                        @"fullName" : @"Josh Nepy"
                        };

NSDictionary *dict3 = @{
                        @"name" : @"Zach",
                        @"desc" : @"Zach is too lazy",
                        @"fullName" : @"Zach Sung"
                        };

NSArray *personArray = @[dict1, dict2, dict3];

//get first person des
NSString *desc = personArray[0][@"desc"];

//get the third full name
NSString *fullName = personArray[2][@"fullName"];
```